# makefile not finding header file from -I include path

Tags: c++, makefile

I have the makefile given below. When I do `make` I get the following error

```
cc  -c -o timing.o timing.c
test_c.c:5:17: fatal error: test.h: No such file or directory
 #include "test.h"
```

I have manually verfied that `test.h` is present in `../include` path. I am not sure why this is not finding the header file.It would be great if someone could help.Also I would expect `g++` instead of `cc`

```
# Makefile template for shared library

CXX = g++ # C++ compiler                                                                                                                                                                     
CXXFLAGS = -fPIC -Wall -Wextra -O2 -g -I../include #CXX flags
LDFLAGS = -lboost_system -shared  # linking flags

RM = rm -f  # rm command

TARGET_LIB = libtest.a # target lib


C_SRCS := test_a.c test_b.c 
CPP_SRCS := test_c.cpp test_d.cpp 
OBJS := $(C_SRCS:.c=.o) $(CPP_SRCS:.cpp=.o)

.PHONY: all 

all: ${TARGET_LIB}

$(TARGET_LIB): $(OBJS) 
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) ${LDFLAGS} -o $@ $^  


.PHONY: clean
clean:
    -${RM} ${TARGET_LIB} ${OBJS}
```

~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not written a rule for building timing.o from timing.c, so Make uses the default rule it has for that.

**But** that rule uses `CFLAGS`, not `CXXFLAGS`. The `CXXFLAGS` variable appears in the rule for building object files from C++ sources.

So modify `CFLAGS` instead of `CXXFLAGS`, and it should work.

Comment: @alvits: You're right, I was making that very correction when I saw your comment.